# WebTestClient not injected

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mocking, integration-testing, spring-webflux

First of all I'm new to the java stack and in my defence I might ask something stupid, thank you for your patience!

**What I need:**

Integration test but without the external requests being made. That means I have to mock a dependency somewhere deeper in the stack than a normal unit test.
I also don't want to load all the stack in the context.

**Expected:**

Be able to mock only the client with @BeanMock and have the test pass. (From my trials this only mocks the first level in depth).

**Actual:**

With the current setup I'm getting

`Error creating bean with name 'com.example.demo.SomeControllerTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'webClient'`

If I use `@WebFluxTest(SomeController.class)` and `ContextConfiguration(...)` the client ends up being null. If I then add the `@TestConfiguration` webflux is complaining about having some annotations in conflict `@Configuration` for example.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

```
@RestController
public class SomeController {
  private final SomeService someService;

  @Autowired
  public SomeController(SomeService someService) {
    this.someService = someService;
  }


  @GetMapping(value = "/endpoint")
  public Mono<String> endpoint() {
    return someService.get();
  }
}


@Service
public class SomeService {
  private final Client client;

  @Autowired
  public SomeService(Client client) {
    this.client = client;
  }

  public Mono<String> get() {
    return client.build().get().retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class);
  }
}


@Component
public class Client {
  private final HttpServletRequest request;

  @Autowired
  public Client(HttpServletRequest request) {
    this.request = request;
  }

  public WebClient build() {
    return WebClient.builder()
      .baseUrl("https://httpstat.us/200")
      .build();
  }
}

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@TestConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(classes = {
  SomeController.class,
  SomeService.class
})
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient
public class SomeControllerTest {
  @Autowired
  private WebTestClient webClient;

  @MockBean
  private Client client;


  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    when(client.build())
      .thenReturn(WebClient.create("https://httpstat.us/201"));
  }

  @Test
  public void deepMocking() {
    webClient.get()
      .uri("/endpoint")
      .exchange()
      .expectStatus().isOk()
      .expectBody(String.class).isEqualTo("201 Created");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebFluxTest(SomeController.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {
   SomeController.class,
   SomeService.class
 })
 public class SomeControllerTest {
   @Autowired
   private WebTestClient webClient;
   // ...
 }
```

This is the required combo, yet i don't understand why there is the need for adding `SomeController.class` to the active context, doesn't `@WebFluxTest` do that as well?

**OR**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {
  SomeController.class,
  SomeService.class,
})
// @AutoConfigureWebTestClient // does absolutely nothing?
public class SomeControllerTest {
  @Autowired
  private SomeController controller;

  // ...

  @Test
  public void deepMocking() {
    WebTestClient.bindToController(controller)
      .build()
      .get()
      .uri("/endpoint")
      .exchange()
      .expectStatus().isOk()
      .expectBody(String.class).isEqualTo("201 Created");
  }
}
```

Comment: Because if you check javadoc of `WebTestClient`, you will see it will instantiate itself with building methods(`buildXxx()`) which needs some controller to test each controller one by one; maybe with autowiring you just provide each controller for this builder as beans, so you need them.

Answer (score 2):

After 03 days struggling, That's how I have solved that:

Thanks a llooottt for : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-5-webclient

```
@WebFluxTest
public class AnimeControllerIntegrTest{

    WebTestClient testClient;

    @Test
    public void get_RA() {

        testClient = WebTestClient.bindToServer().baseUrl("http://localhost:8080/animes").build();

        RestAssuredWebTestClient
                .given()
                .webTestClient(testClient)

                .when()
                .get()

                .then()
                .statusCode(OK.value())

                .body("name" ,hasItem("paulo"))
        ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the error says that you are getting an error when trying to autowire the 
`WebTestClient` bean inside the `SomeControllerTest` class you can't just autowire the WebTestClient it has to be changed to

```
WebTestClient testClient = WebTestClient
  .bindToServer()
  .baseUrl("http://localhost:8080")
  .build();
```

you can find more on the WebClient from this article 
http://www.baeldung.com/spring-5-webclient

Comment: `@AutoConfigureWebTestClient` should according to the docs provide a web test client when used with `@SpringBootTest` instead of `@WebFluxTest`. Not sure on how it is configured but at least Intellij picks up the bean as being defined somewhere, weird.